# Bootstrap dropdown stops working after appending <tr> to different <table>

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a page for an app where the admin reviews a submitted objective. Each objective is a `<tr>` inside 1 of 3 different tables. "review", "complete", and "submitted" are the three tables.

There is a btn-group on each `<tr>` with an option to approve, revert or deny depending on which status it currently has. When the status is changed the  containing the objective is removed and appended to the proper table.

When it moves the  the btn-group dropdown then stop working. I thought that it may need to have `.dropdown();` added after it was appended, but I cant make it work.

Not sure how to setup a JSfiddle with this b/c of the use of server side data. anyone have a suggestion for me?

Here is a JSfiddle with all of my current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xKLN4/

```
    approve: function(clicked) {
        var id = clicked.attr('data-id');
        $.post('<?=URL::to('supervisor/approve_objective')?>',{
            'id' : id,
            'trainee_id' : '<?=$trainee->id?>',
            'status' : 'completed' //or whatever it should be, one of 'submitted'|'completed'|'review'
        },
        function(data, textStatus){
            console.log('Post return data:');
            console.log(data);
            var status = data.status_translated;
            var lbl = $('.label-'+data.object.objective_id);
                    lbl.fadeOut('fast');
                    lbl.attr('class','label label-'+data.object.status+' label-'+data.object.objective_id)
                       .text(data.object.status_translated)
                       .fadeIn('fast');
                       clicked.closest('tr').children('td, th')
                               .animate({ padding: 0 })
                               .wrapInner('<div />')
                               .children()
                               .slideUp(function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });

                    var row = clicked.closest('tr').html();

                    $('#approve-objectives-completed > tbody:last').append('<tr>'+row+'</tr>')
                                                                   .children('.dropdown-toggle')
                                                                   .dropdown();


        });


    },
```

Edited to add code

Comment: Set up the jsFiddle to append the html elements without making the ajax call. i.e. just append them on btn clicks.

Comment: I have create a version without the server side code: http://jsfiddle.net/nmM6c/

Comment: did you have a second to take a look at my JSfiddle. thank you :)

Comment: I just had some time to look at it, adding my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown is not working due to the div that is being added by `wrapInner('<div />')`

One solution is to remove that div in the last `td` after you have copied everything into the new row...

```
approve: function(clicked) {

      clicked.closest('tr').children('td, th')
             .animate({ padding: 0 })
             .wrapInner('<div />')
             .children()
             .slideUp(function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove(); });

      var row = clicked.closest('tr').html();

      $('#approve-objectives-completed > tbody:last').append('<tr>'+row+'</tr>')

      //Remove div       
      var $lastTdDiv = $('#approve-objectives-completed > tbody > tr:last > td:last > div');  
      var contents = $lastTdDiv.contents();
      $lastTdDiv.replaceWith(contents);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mYZD/1/) with my changes in the 'approve' function